# I cannot click on a button while automating a web-server using selenium python

Tags: selenium, browser-automation

### Info

I want to automate the web-server http://bioinfo.unipune.ac.in/IRESPred/IRESPred.html using python selenium.

### html code

```
<input name="fileToUpload" type="file" class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-sm" xpath="1">
```

### code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Users\Amardeep\Downloads\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://bioinfo.unipune.ac.in/IRESPred/IRESPred.html")
time.sleep(2)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'fileToUpload']").click()
```

### output error

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

### Tried solutions

I used different x-paths to click the button which opens a window to upload a file-path but button is not clickable.  I used find element by name,class name,css selector but it also not worked. How should I solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @dimay for corrcting my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code - (I'm using Chromedriver and you are using Edge, so modify code accordingly)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("http://bioinfo.unipune.ac.in/IRESPred/IRESPred.html")
time.sleep(2)
Upload_btn = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='fileToUpload']")))
action.move_to_element(Upload_btn).click().perform()
```

I'm able to click on a button using the above code, let me know if you have any issues or you face any error message.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. The above code has performed well and I am able to click the button.

Comment: It if works for you then you can mark it as answer.